# SCCM+ MS Office 2013 deployment

Tags: deployment, microsoft-office-365, sccm, vbscript, microsoft-office

This is a 2 part question.

Issue: I've created a script that executes the following scripts (in order) Officescrub10.vbs(created by microsoft), LyncRemove2010.vbs(i created), and Office2013Install.vbs script(silent install of 2013 via Microsoft). Right now it uses .txt  for flags to know when each part is done. Also it reboots/logs in as system user during install.

Problem: I found out I need to use SCCM to deploy script, instead of creating a GPO. I've never used SCCM (always a GPO).

Question:

1.) If I deployed masterdeploy2013.vbs via unc path, what would my best option via SCCM? How would I deploy the script via SCCM Server?

2.) The goal is to uninstall Office 2010 & then install 2013. Could I just do this via SCCM with out scripts?  I want simple but don't know how to make it simple via SCCM Server.

If I use SCCM can I create to deploy to a test user (single user) at 1st?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you have to use SCCM?  If you are running via GPO today - what issues are you encountering?  There is no functional reason SCCM would have to be used - it can make deployment and tracking easier, but the setup certainly is not.

Comment: System administrators have blocked access to create a gpo and I was told to use sccm. Trust me I would use a gpo!

Comment: I could argue but I'm a system administrator from a smaller firm that got aquierd..things are strange.

Answer (score 1):

Well to deploy a script or application is the same in SCCM.  Assuming SCCM is already configured you need to setup your application files and deployment packages.  The wizards in SCCM are pretty straight forward with walking you thru the process.

However - you have multiple scripts you want to deploy and run in order.  You can either try to wrap those up into a single package or you you need to configure a task sequence to execute them.  I'm not a strong SCCM guy or I would provide you with Step by Step on it.

You may want to consider Microsoft guide on deploying O365 Office Pro Plus with SCCM here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn708063.aspx

You can first run your uninstaller script and then push out the ProPlus installation via the above guide.